# JavaScript の for 文でテーブルを作成したい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px;
  /* 枠線指定 */
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* セルの線を重ねる */
}

.cell {
  width: 100px;
}

.title_area {
  height: 30px;
}

.up_down_border {
  border-top-style: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.bottom_border {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.top_border {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>   
  <meta charset=UTF-8>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>   
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>red</td>
      <td>blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">サンプル<br>サンプル<br>メニュー</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="up_down_border">サンプル1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="up_down_border">サンプル2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="up_down_border">サンプル3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">サンプル<br>menu<br>date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bottom_border">サンプル4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="up_down_border">サンプル5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="top_border">サンプル6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

for文を使って下記のようにtableを作成しました。理想形に近づけたいのですが、上手くいきません。例えばですが、rowspanやbrの箇所など、ここからどう書いていていいのか分かりません。分かる方ご教示頂きたいです。よろしくお願いします。

↓forを使ったtable作成

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerHTML = 'データ' + (i + 1) + "-" + (j + 1);
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  $("body").append(table);
// テーブルの外周線の太さを設定
table.border = "2";
// セルの内周余白量を設定
table.cellPadding = "4";
// セルの外周余白量を設定
table.cellSpacing = "0";
})
```

↓理想形のtable、for文を使ってこの形にしたい。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>   
  <meta charset=UTF-8>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>   
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>red</td>
      <td>blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">サンプル<br>サンプル<br>メニュー</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="up_down_border">サンプル1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="up_down_border">サンプル2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="up_down_border">サンプル3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">サンプル<br>menu<br>date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bottom_border">サンプル4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="up_down_border">サンプル5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="top_border">サンプル6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

```
td {
  border: solid 1px;
  /* 枠線指定 */
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* セルの線を重ねる */
}

.cell {
  width: 100px;
}

.title_area {
  height: 30px;
}

.up_down_border {
  border-top-style: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.bottom_border {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.top_border {
  border-top: none;
}
```

追記
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: サンプル１～サンプル３のところは、<td class="up_down_border">の部分が共通なのでForループで生成することが出来ると思いますが、サンプル4～サンプル6のところは、ｔｄのクラスがそれぞれ異なるので、forループでは難しいですね。["bottom_border","up_down_border","top_border"]のような配列と、[サンプル4,サンプル5,サンプル6]のような配列を用意しておいて、forループで組み合わせるというのは可能でしょうjが。

Comment: 変数を作ってからその変数をテーブルのセルの中に入れたいです、そもそも規則性がないからforでは難しいでしょうか。。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

もう少しきれいに書くことは可能ですがこんな感じでどうでしょうか？

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const table = document.createElement("table");

  const tableBody = {
    rows: [
      [{ value: "red" }, { value: "blue" }],
      [{ value: "サンプル<br>サンプル<br>メニュー", rowSpan: 4 }],
      [{ value: "サンプル1", className: "up_down_border" }],
      [{ value: "サンプル2", className: "up_down_border" }],
      [{ value: "サンプル3", className: "up_down_border" }],
      [{ value: "サンプル<br>menu<br>date", rowSpan: 4 }],
      [{ value: "サンプル4", className: "bottom_border" }],
      [{ value: "サンプル5", className: "bottom_border" }],
      [{ value: "サンプル6", className: "top_border" }]
    ]
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < tableBody.rows.length; i++) {
    const cols = tableBody.rows[i];
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
      const col = cols[j];
      const td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = col.value;
      if (col.className) {
        td.className = col.className;
      }
      if (col.rowSpan >= 0) {
        td.rowSpan = col.rowSpan;
      }
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  document.querySelector("body").append(table);

  // テーブルの外周線の太さを設定
  table.border = "2";
  // セルの内周余白量を設定
  table.cellPadding = "4";
  // セルの外周余白量を設定
  table.cellSpacing = "0";
});
```

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px;
  /* 枠線指定 */
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* セルの線を重ねる */
}

.cell {
  width: 100px;
}

.title_area {
  height: 30px;
}

.up_down_border {
  border-top-style: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.bottom_border {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.top_border {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 凄いです。ありがとうございます！回答を頂いてなんですが、blueの下にあるはずのセルがredのセルの下にいってしまって、blueの下に空白ができている状態なんですが、、、

Comment: 理想形のテーブルをスニペットで確認できるようにしました。ご確認ください。

Comment: と思ったらコードの不具合でしたすみません。修正しました。

Comment: 助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 一点だけよろしいでしょうか。if (col.rowSpan > 0) { ここなんですが0にはどんな意味があるのでしょうか？if(col.rowSpan)だけではダメなのでしょうか。

Comment: (追記)rowSpanは0も可なので、`rowSpan >=0`に修正しました。

Comment: JavaScriptにおける`!!0`の結果は`false`なので、0が来た場合に、rowSpanが設定されなくなります。